# Applescript - create subfolders according to the 3 first letters of filenames

Tags: applescript

I have thousands of files in a folder named:

00101 , 00102, 00103, 00201, 00202, 00207, xxx, 19801, 19802, xxx

I would like to create subfolder according to the 3 first letters of the files, in order to have folder named

001 --> which include all the files 00101, 00102, 00103..

xxx --> xxx01, xxx02...

Would it be possible to do that using apple script?

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions

- To get the first 3 characters use `set prefix to text 1 thru 3 of fileName`
- To copy the files use `ditto` of the shell. It is able to create all intermediate subfolders if necessary.

  ```
  do shell script "/usr/bin/ditto " & quoted form of "/path/to/fileName.ext" & space & quoted form of ("/path/to/baseFolder/" & prefix & "/" & fileName)
  ```